# Is it possible to flash custom kernel from older Android version?

Tags: rom-flashing, kernel, xiaomi-pocophone-f1

I've recently rooted my POCO F1 and installed a custom ROM on it. I've tried to find a custom kernel for POCO F1 that is specifically for Android 14 and can't seem to find it.

Is it possible for me to use a custom kernel from an older version like Android 13? I want to try the NGK kernel on my phone, but there's no Android 14 version.